# last element in a deep list

Tags: prolog

So if the input is **L=[1,[2,3,4],5]**, the output should be **R = [4,5]**.
The code for last element in a regular list is

```
last([X],X].
last([H|T],X):-last(T,X).
```

Comment: What is the result for [1,[2,3]] ? "Ok...Solution, please?" surely not the good way to have an answer !

Comment: Do you mean all last elements of all sublists at all nesting levels? Such that for @joel76 's example it would be [1,3]?

Comment: for l =[1,[2,3]], r=[1,3],yes, alexander.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly elegant Prolog, but I think it will do what you want:

```
deeplast([L], X) :-
    deeplast(L, X).
deeplast([X], X) :-
    atomic(X).
deeplast([H|T], X) :-
    atomic(H),
    deeplast(T, X).
deeplast([H|T], X) :-
    compound(H),
    deeplast(H, Y),
    deeplast(T, Z),
    X = [Y, Z].
```

Comment: Very true, I hadn't covered the case where the final term in the list was a compound too. I think the edited version now covers that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly edited version of Peter's anwers :

```
deeplast([L], X) :-
    deeplast(L, X).

deeplast([X], X) :-
    atomic(X).

deeplast([H|T], X) :-
    atomic(H),
    deeplast(T, X).

deeplast([H|T], X) :-

    deeplast(H, Y),
    deeplast(T, Z),
    X = Z.


?- deeplast([1,[2,3],4,[5,[6,8]]],R).
   R = 8
```